# Determine all homomorphisms $\phi: K\rightarrow Aut(H)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

*Let $H$ be cyclic group of order 7 and let $K$ be cyclic of order 3.

(a) Determine all homomorphisms $\phi: K\rightarrow Aut(H)$.*

**My attempt:** Since $K$ is cyclic, any one of the two generator of $K$ will be mapped as the generator of $Im(K)$ in $Aut(H)$. Since "if $f$ is a homomorphism, then $|f(x)|||x|$.", so the $|Im(K)|||K|$ thus $|Im(K)|$ could be 1 or 3. Since $H$ is also cyclic, $Aut(H)\cong\mathbb{Z}_7^X$, so the size, by Euler's function, of $Aut(H)$ is 6. Then I'm stuck...

*(b) For each homomorphism describe the corresponding semi direct product $H\rtimes_\phi K$.*

**My attempt**: Once I have all the homomorphism from (a), I'll have the operation of $(h,k)(h',k')$. I'm not sure what else I'm suppose to say for the "description."

*(c) Determine which semi direct products from (b) are isomorphic to each other.*

I'm not sure how to do this...

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: $\text{Aut}(\Bbb Z_7) \cong \Bbb Z_6$.

So you're looking for homomorphisms between two cyclic groups, which simplfies things.

Secondly, it suffices to consider $\phi(1)$ (or more generally, any generator of $K$). The image of such a generator can only be of order $1$, or order $3$.

There are thus three possible homomorphisms, resulting in two distinct isomorphism classes of semi-direct products.

That should get you started.

By "description", what is probably meant is describing them in terms of groups you already know, or by generators and relations. The non-abelian group may prove a bit harder than the abelian one.

Comment: Thank you, but why is that "resulting in two distinct isomorphism classes of semi-direct products?"

Comment: You have three distinct homomorphisms $K \to \text{Aut}(H)$. Your task is to show that two of them yield isomorphic groups.

Comment: I know that $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_7)\cong\mathbb{Z}_7^*$, but why is $\mathbb{Z}_7^*$ is cyclic?

Comment: Without using finite field to prove?

Comment: There are six units in $\Bbb Z_7$, and each of them yields an automorphism  of $\Bbb Z_7$ by $a \mapsto ka$ (or writing $\Bbb Z_7$ multiplicatively as $C_7$ the automorphisms $a \mapsto a^k$). These six units form a group, which is an abelian group of order $6$, hence cyclic.

Comment: since $\mathbb{Z}_7$ is a specific case, so I can check that $\mathbb{Z}_7^*$ is cyclic. But when in general for any prime $p$, how can you prove that it is cyclic?